# Conversion from Uint8Array to fs.CreateReadStream in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, fs

Given a Uint8Array (or a bin received using atob), can we directly make it as a fs.createReadStream instance in nodeJS?

Actually I need to do :

```
var Pdf = bucket.file('xyz.pdf');

readableInstanceStream.pipe(Pdf.createWriteStream({
            metadata: {
            contentType: 'application/pdf',
            metadata: {
                custom: 'metadata'
            }
            }
        }))
```